# Как правильно локализовать тему wordpress?

Tags: php, html, wordpress, локализация

Всем привет. У меня вопрос по файлу локализации темы wordpress. Добавил в файл темы строчку:

```
<li class='label'><span data-label='". __('Filter','qode') ."'>". __('Filter','qode') ."</span><i class='icon-angle-down'></i>
```

где для `__('Filter')` хочу сделать перевод на русский.
 Скачал папку с темой, запустил редактор poedit и хочу с или отредактировать существующий файл локализации ru_RU.po или создать новый, но получаю ошибку:

[image: ошибка].

Ошибка Poedit
Подробности:

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Poedit\GettextTools\bin\xgettext.exe Non-ASCII
>   string at js/jquery.prettyPhoto.js:7 Please specify the source
>   encoding through --from-code

Элементы каталога, возможно, неверны.
Не удалось обновить каталог.
Как правильно это сделать?

Comment: Внимательно прочитайте документацию по poedit. Ничего сложного там нет. Но в первый раз, мне кажется, многие путаются с этим.

Comment: @s976 а кроме общих фраз - можете сказать что-либо конкретное?

Comment: Какую ошибку Вы получаете? Что написано в details?

Comment: @s976 вверху скрин я специально прикрепил - вот такую ошибку

Comment: К сожалению я не вижу картинку... Мой провайдер иногда фильтрует по-ошибке...

Comment: @s976 вверху продублировал описание ошибки

Comment: Может попробуйте установить (в установках каталога) кодировку как UTF-8 (если еще не установлено так).

Comment: UTF-8 установлено как раз-таки..

Comment: А кодировка файла jquery.prettyPhoto.js какая? UTF-8?

Comment: @s976 угу......

Comment: А без этого файла не идет? (для данного файла вообще не нужна локализация)

Answer (score 2):

Открываем каталог - `Open`.
Выбираем нужный `.po` файл.
(Пробуем нажать на update но получаем ошибку - файлы не найдены. Конечно, ведь программа не знает где их искать)
Переходим в Catalogue->properties, там переходим к вкладке Sources paths.
Нажимаем на кнопку new item
Добавляем путь к корневому каталогу темы относительно .po файла. Обычно .po файл находится в папке languages (расположенной в корневом каталоге темы), поэтому нужно добавить такой путь: `..`
Теперь все должно работать. То есть можно заново нажать на `update`

Comment: и все равно вылазит та же ошибка..((

Answer (score -2):

Попробуй  в Catalog → Properties → Source Keywords удалить "_".